# Critical points of an absolute value periodic function in Sympy

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I want to look for the critical points of the following periodic function `abs(sin(x))` for `x` in the Real set.

So far I have tried:

```
from sympy import *

x = Symbol("x")

f = abs(sin(x))

solveset(diff(f), x, S.Reals)
```

with no luck, I then tried to unpack the absolute value into a piecewise function:

```
as_piece = Piecewise((sin(x), sin(x)>=0), (-sin(x), sin(x)<0))

solveset(diff(as_piece), x, S.Reals)
```

and again `solveset` cannot solve it. The interesting thing is that `solve` is able to solve `as_piece` but of course returns only the first two critical points as its output is not a `set`.

Comment: You should declare `x` as real or `f` and `as_piece` are not equivalent. The function is not differentiable at its minima so I'm not sure what answer you expect for the "critical points" here. Maybe it would be better to find the critical points of `f**2` instead.

Comment: I'm interested in the critical points, not the minima. In this case, the function has maxima which are also critical points and in the maxima the function is differentiable.

Comment: It is still unclear what you actually want but `solveset((sin(x)**2).diff(x), x)` will give both the minima and maxima.

Comment: Sorry but, what is unclear? I want the points in which the function is differentiable and the derivative at that point is zero. I don't want maxima and minima, could be either a saddle point (of course in this case there aren't any). And `f**2` is not what I want because the function is differentiable in the whole domain. Is a toy example for didactic purpose.

Comment: Your previous response said "the function has maxima which are *also* critical points". Now you have made it clear that (in the given example) you are only interested in the maxima but the "also" made your statement ambiguous.

Comment: I think this is just something that can be improved in `solveset` so I suggest opening a GitHub issue

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I’ll open an issue asap. Thanks again

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/21858